# printf preventing race conditions

Tags: c, multithreading, openmp, race-condition

In this example code I do a summation from `i=0` to `i=n` and then add the result to itself `k` times, where `k` is the number of threads. I purposely did it without `critical` (surrounding the `printf` and `ans += ans`) to cause race conditions. However, to my surprise, no race condition happened:

```
int summation_with_operation_after_it_wrong1(int n, int k) {
        int ans = 0;
        #pragma omp parallel firstprivate(n) num_threads(k)
        {
                int i; /* Private */
                #pragma omp for schedule(dynamic) reduction(+:ans)
                for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                        ans += i;
                }
                printf("Thread %d ans=%d\n", omp_get_thread_num(), ans);
                ans += ans;    
        }
        return ans;
}
```

Using `n=10` and `k=4`, the output is (always the same, except for thread order):

```
Thread 1 ans=45
Thread 3 ans=45
Thread 0 ans=45
Thread 2 ans=45
720
```

However, I did noticed something odd about it. `ans` was always 45, instead of

```
Thread 3 ans=45
Thread 0 ans=90
Thread 2 ans=180
Thread 1 ans=360
720
```

When using `critical`. So I moved the `printf` to after the `ans += ans` to see what it was doing, and, for my surprise, the predicted race conditions started to occur all the time!

```
Thread 3 ans=90
Thread 1 ans=135
Thread 2 ans=90
Thread 0 ans=135
135
```

So... How does the `printf` prevented race conditions? And how does that sum ended up to be 720? I'm completely lost here.

Comment: Perhaps it is because `printf()` has some 'thread safety' built into it, which forces some serialization.  I've not checked, but there are functions like [`putc_unlocked()`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/putc_unlocked.html), but `printf()` is written in terms of `putc()` for character output.  So, simply using `printf()` may impose some sequencing, leaving the program better behaved than you'd expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Section 1.4 of the latest [OpenMP standard](http://www.openmp.org/mp-documents/OpenMP4.0.0.pdf) specifies what is the result of a race condition (emphasis mine):

> If multiple threads write without synchronization to the same memory
>   unit, including cases due to atomicity considerations as described
>   above, then a data race occurs. Similarly, if at least one thread
>   reads from a memory unit and at least one thread writes without
>   synchronization to that same memory unit, including cases due to
>   atomicity considerations as described above, then a data race occurs.
>   **If a data race occurs then the result of the program is unspecified.**

What you notice is completely consistent with the statement in bold. In fact, as the behavior in a program containing a data-race is unspecified, it makes little sense to argue why a particular output results from a given run. In particular, it is only by chance that you obtained `720` when inserting a `printf` before the `ans+=ans` command, and there's no guarantee that you will always encounter the same behavior.

Comment: I had to run the code 100,000 times until the result was different. It seems that, as @mah suggested, `printf`, being an expensive call, was messing with the timing.

Answer (score 1):

`printf()` is a very expensive call to make, and it's not a surprise that using it changes your race condition timing. A better option to see what's happening is to create an array (in advance) to store your results and have each thread deposit its result into this array where you're currently performing the print; then do the actual `printf()` after all the work has completed.

Comment: You mean something like [this](http://pastebin.com/VNyvwVhL)? It shows that `printf` is preventing the race condition, which I already noticed. (Using `after` after the `ans += ans` instead of `before` before also results in race conditions and doesn't explain the summation apparently without race conditions caused by `printf`).

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant. What I was getting at is that you should expect expensive actions like printf to change your timing so using it to assist with debugging a timing problem is often not productive unless you can remove it from the timing sensitive code. Storing results in an array like this is an easy way to accomplish this since `array[index]=someinteger` is only a few CPU instructions while `printf(...)` is likely to be several thousand instructions.